# Will DynamoDB API BatchWriteItem always write to the table in the order of the PutRequests in RequestItems?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Simple example for clarification: The JSON below is sent to DynamoDB using BatchWriteItem. Will it always be processed in the exact same order? I must have "Message one" written to the table first, then "Message Two" second, and "Message Three" third.

```
"RequestItems": {
  "TABLE": [
    {
      "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "Message one."
          },
          "ID": {
            "S": "S103"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "Message two."
          },
          "ID": {
            "S": "S104"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "Message three."
          },
          "ID": {
            "S": "S105"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about the order?

Comment: It is required.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the DynamoDB docs that suggest there is an ordering guarantee when using `BatchWriteItem`.  However, the docs do say

> The individual PutItem and DeleteItem operations specified in BatchWriteItem are atomic; however BatchWriteItem as a whole is not. If any requested operations fail because the table's provisioned throughput is exceeded or an internal processing failure occurs, the failed operations are returned in the UnprocessedItems response parameter. You can investigate and optionally resend the requests. Typically, you would call BatchWriteItem in a loop. Each iteration would check for unprocessed items and submit a new BatchWriteItem request with those unprocessed items until all items have been processed.

The very idea that some of the requests may end up as `unprocessed` suggests that order is *not* guaranteed.

I don't have specific knowledge about how `BatchWriteItem` ordering is or isn't handled, but wanted to point this out in the event your use case can't handle that uncertainty.

If order *is* important, you could just fire off multiple requests in-order.

If you're able to share more about the details of your use-case, I'm sure the community could make recommendations that directly address the problem you're trying to solve.